# Ruby using helpers in single script

Tags: ruby

I am wanting to use the pluralize text helper in a ruby script I am writing, but can't find anywhere on how to include Rails helpers in a single ruby script. I know you need to include the helper module and require the helpers, but like I said I am not 100% sure on how to get it to work.

Comment: Rails is a framework and so has a necessary amount of coupling. In RoR 3 they tried to minimize this but your best bet is to grab that module, try to use it, and see what it asks for when running. The easiest way of course would just be to include the whole framework and only use the bits you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
require 'action_view'
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
puts pluralize(2, 'person')
```

(Requires gem actionpack installed, tested with ruby 1.9.1, actionpack 3.0.3)

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use the inflector in ActiveSupport, assuming you have the activesupport gem installed:

```
$ irb
>> require 'active_support/inflector'
=> true
>> "person".pluralize
=> "people"
```